# Load a new level after all coins have been collected

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using coins as a game object. And i m using this code for collecting all coins and loading a new scene but i m unable to do so.

```
public int score;// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

}


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider col){
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "coin1"|| col.gameObject.tag=="Finish") {
    score +=1;
        AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(CC, transform.position);
        DestroyObject(col.gameObject);
        addScore();

    }


}
void addScore(){
    score++; 
    if( score == 2 )
    { 
        Application.LoadLevel(1); 
    }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When writing the function you should see that there is a warning about the line. It states that `Application.LoadLevel()` is deprecated (=obsolete).

Instead, you're supposed to use [**SceneManager.LoadScene()**](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SceneManagement.SceneManager.LoadScene.html).

Comment: @HassanRazaJaffry : Good. Glad I could help! Please remember to mark my post as the accepted answer by pressing the check mark on its left.